# Google map displayed in modal in Ionic 2

Tags: google-maps, typescript, ionic2

I am developing app in Ionic 2, and I want to display map in a modal. Problem is I can't get it to work. Same code works on normal page, but not in modal. I tried using web version of google maps API and even native `cordova` plugin, but result is the same, blank map in modal, working map on page. Any advice how to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you provide a code snippet for both modal and normal page?

Answer (score 1):

You should [set the underneath page to transparent](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/native-google-maps-not-working-inside-a-modal/89171?u=atmo).

Here is my working code for calling map modal

html

```
<ion-content [style.opacity]="isModal ? 0 : 1" padding>
  <button ion-button item-right >
    <ion-icon name="add" (click)="getLocation()"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-content>
```

typescript

```
getLocation() {
  this.isModal = true;
  let mapModal = this.modalCtrl.create(MapModalPage);
  mapModal.onDidDismiss((data) => {
    this.isModal = false;
    if(data) {
      this.location = data.location;
      this.locImage = data.image;
    }
  });
  mapModal.present();
}
```